Created inputs are only submitting the first input's value, while the rest are blank. Why?
This is a ToDoList project  from TheOdinProject. I have been stuck on this part of code for days, as my inputs will console.log empty strings in the module createTodos. I can't seem to figure out why the first input, name, would work, but the other 3 would not. Does anyone know why?
Module createProject.js
import { createTodos } from "./createTodos";

function appendInputsAndButton(currentProject) {
  let inputContainer = document.createElement("div");
  inputContainer.className = "input-container";

  inputContainer.innerHTML = `<input class="name"></input> <input class="description"></input>  <input class="dueDate"></input>  <input class="priority"></input>
         <button class="submit-todos">Submit</button> <button class="close">X</button> `;
  currentProject.appendChild(inputContainer);
  
  inputContainer.querySelector('.submit-todos').addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    event.stopPropagation();
    createTodos();
  })

  inputContainer.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    currentProject.removeChild(inputContainer);
  } )
}



function makeProject(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    todos: [],
  };
}

export let projects = [];
export function createProject() {
  projects.push(
    makeProject(document.querySelector("#projectName").value.trim())
  );
  console.log(projects);
  let archives = document.querySelector(".container");
  archives.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    let project = projects[i];
    let newProject = document.createElement("div");
    newProject.className = "project";
    newProject.textContent = project.name;
    newProject.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let currentProject = e.target;
      appendInputsAndButton(currentProject);
    });
    archives.appendChild(newProject);
  }
}

Module 2 createTodos.js
import { projects } from "./createProject"

function makeTodos (name, description, dueDate, priority){
    return {
        name: name,
        description: description,
        dueDate: dueDate,
        priority: priority,
        
    }
}

export function createTodos(){
    console.log("createTodos function executed");
    const name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
    const description = document.querySelector('.description').value;
    const dueDate = document.querySelector('.dueDate').value;
    const priority = document.querySelector('.priority').value;

    console.log("Name:", name);
    console.log("Description:", description);
    console.log("Due Date:", dueDate);
    console.log("Priority:", priority);

    // projects[0] is just to test
    projects[0].todos.push(makeTodos);
    console.log("Updated Todos:", projects[0].todos);
}

Module 3 index.js
import './styles.css';
import {createProject} from './createProject.js'


const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-btn');
submitButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    createProject();
})



projects[0].todos.push(makeTodos); doesn't call the makeTodos function, it just puts a reference to the function in the array.

It should be projects[0].todos.push(makeTodos(name, description, dueDate, priority))

The two modules shouldn't import from each other.

Comments, maybe useful, maybe not. HTML input elements don't have closing tags, so you can remove all "". If the inputs are in a form, in order to be successful and be submitted with the form, they must have a name. Only the first has a name. Giving a form element a name of "name" masks the form's name property (if the input is in a form…).
